# Keycloak Gateway: Programmatically keeping the token active

Tags: authentication, keycloak, openid

I am looking into using Keycloak to replace our in-house legacy system. I have successfully setup key cloak and can get a token but I need to keep it active. My plan is to have an action filter that can get the token from the request and call something on Keycloak to stop it from timing out. I thought by calling this:

http://localhost:8080/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect

[image: error]

But as you can see this does not work, any ideas, please?

I have created a test app to call this

http://localhost:8080/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect

Every 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using refresh token as the way to get new access token when they expire.

This blog post can be a good starting point
https://huongdanjava.com/get-access-token-using-refresh-token-with-keycloak.html

Comment: Thanks I was trying to avoid that because of the way the legacy code is written Client and Server side

Comment: the alternative is to make the access tokens more long-lived, you can make them live for months or years, then it is a trade-of between security and convenience.

Comment: That sounds like a dodgy idea lol, its just going to be more work than I planned using the refresh token :-(

Comment: The alternative is to introduce the BFF pattern and handle all tokens in the backend, see https://youtu.be/lEnbi4KClVw

Comment: Thanks that's basically what I am doing